# Determine if a date is GMT or BST

Tags: r, timezone

I have a bunch of dates (in UTC) e.g.

```
> dates <- as.POSIXct(c('2019-01-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-08-01'), tz = 'UTC')
> dates
[1] "2019-01-01 UTC" "2019-07-01 UTC" "2019-08-01 UTC"
```

I want to know if each date in my vector is during GMT or BST.

So the above would give

```
"GMT" "BST" "BST"
```

Comment: `tz(dates)` will give you to timezones. If it is UTC, then it is GMT also. BST is UTC+1. It should reflect in the timezone itself. Your dates has all UTC

Comment: You would need a time also, or you could infer midnight or noon, but you would get different results near transitions depending on what time you are inferring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the best way of doing it, but got what I wanted using

```
library(lubridate)
ifelse(hour(force_tz(as.POSIXct(as.Date(dates)), tz = 'Europe/London')) == 1, 'BST', 'GMT')
```